# How to get Remote device mac address by NFC SSP

Tags: bluetooth, nfc, android-bluetooth

I want to know how to get remote device MAC address when bluetooth SSP(simple Pairing) using NFC.

According to Bluetooth SSP using NFC Application Document, Remote Device(a.k.a Phone) is providing Select Msg by NDEF when received Request Msg from NFC device.

My question is, do all Android phones send Select msg? (including Phones MAC address)

I can find this word in document

Record Type Name:application/vnd.bluetooth.ep.oob

If i understand what I mean, i can use that MIME-type to induce Android's behavior.

If so, is it possible for an NFC device to receive the BT MAC address of the phone through NFC with only Android operation without a specific app?